# Why does setting a MultiIndex dataframe with a Series give a column of NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

The following code illustrates my question:

```
In [2]: idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5)

In [3]: idx
Out[3]:
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-04', '2011-01-05'],
    dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

In [4]: midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['100', '200'], idx])

In [5]: midx
Out[5]: MultiIndex(levels=[['100', '200'],
    [2011-01-01 00:00:00, 2011-01-02 00:00:00, 2011-01-03 00:00:00, 2011-01-04 00:00:00, 2011-01-05 00:00:00]], 
    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [6]: test_data = pd.DataFrame(
            2*[[1, 2], [NaN, 3], [4, NaN], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
            index=midx, columns=['quant1', 'quant2']
        )

In [7]: test_data
Out[7]: 
                quant1  quant2
100 2011-01-01     1.0     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     4.0     NaN
    2011-01-04     5.0     6.0
    2011-01-05     7.0     8.0
200 2011-01-01     1.0     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     4.0     NaN
    2011-01-04     5.0     6.0
    2011-01-05     7.0     8.0

In [8]: new_data = pd.DataFrame([11, 12, 13, 14, 15], index=idx, columns=['quant1'])

In [9]: new_data
Out[9]: 
            quant1
2011-01-01      11
2011-01-02      12
2011-01-03      13
2011-01-04      14
2011-01-05      15

In [10]: test_data.loc['100', 'quant1'] = new_data

In [11]: test_data
Out[11]: 
                quant1  quant2
100 2011-01-01     NaN     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     NaN     NaN
    2011-01-04     NaN     6.0
    2011-01-05     NaN     8.0
200 2011-01-01     1.0     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     4.0     NaN
    2011-01-04     5.0     6.0
    2011-01-05     7.0     8.0
```

Why is the `['100', 'quant1']` data segment filled with `NaN`s instead of the numbers from `new_data`?

I have found that using

```
test_data.loc['100', 'quant1'] = new_data.values
```

does work, but I would like to understand what makes `Pandas` do this. The sub-slice has the same dimensions and even the same Index as the new data, so even though I do suspect that this has to do with indexing/alignment, I don't really understand how or why - my expectation would be that as long as you're using the exact same index as what you're assigning to, that would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Pandas aligns the indices of the receiving dataframe and the series providing new data.  When it does, it fails to find the relevant index it is looking for.

`test_data.loc['100', 'quant2']` has an index entry of `('100', '2011-01-01')` while `new_data` has an entry of `'2011-01-01'`.  Those are not the same.

#### Work Around 1

Use the `values` attribute and skip Pandas trying to align

```
test_data.loc['100', 'quant1'] = new_data.values

test_data

                quant1  quant2
100 2011-01-01    11.0     2.0
    2011-01-02    12.0     3.0
    2011-01-03    13.0     NaN
    2011-01-04    14.0     6.0
    2011-01-05    15.0     8.0
200 2011-01-01     1.0     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     4.0     NaN
    2011-01-04     5.0     6.0
    2011-01-05     7.0     8.0
```

---

#### Work Around 2

Use `pd.concat` to add an index level

```
test_data.loc['100', 'quant1'] = pd.concat({'100': new_data})

test_data

                quant1  quant2
100 2011-01-01    11.0     2.0
    2011-01-02    12.0     3.0
    2011-01-03    13.0     NaN
    2011-01-04    14.0     6.0
    2011-01-05    15.0     8.0
200 2011-01-01     1.0     2.0
    2011-01-02     NaN     3.0
    2011-01-03     4.0     NaN
    2011-01-04     5.0     6.0
    2011-01-05     7.0     8.0
```